# Can I somehow render more stuff (opengl)

Tags: c++, opengl, c++14

I'm trying to render lots of stuff with OpenGL 3.3 Am i missing some tricks to make this faster?

Does it matter if I use glBufferData or glBufferSubData?

I have coded OpenGL for 5 days now, so I know that there are lots of unkown uknowns to me. And those are what i'm looking for, can you point me to any ways of making this even faster?

I think i'm using what's called "Instanced Rendering". All my stuff is rendered via a single glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex call.

Did I miss any relevant code? There's so much of it that I can't really paste it all here.

I'v gotten as far as 20000 objects with 24 vertices using the following code:

Called once per mesh at start, not during frames.

```
void Mesh::initMesh(IndexedModel const & p_model)
{
  d->drawCount = p_model.indices.size();

  glGenVertexArrays(1, &(d->vertexArrayObject));
  glBindVertexArray(d->vertexArrayObject);

  glGenBuffers(eNumBuffers, d->vertexArrayBuffers);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[ePosition_Vb]);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(p_model.positions[0]) * p_model.positions.size(), p_model.positions.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eTexCoord_Vb]);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(p_model.texCoords[0]) * p_model.texCoords.size(), p_model.texCoords.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eNormal_Vb]);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(p_model.normals[0]) * p_model.normals.size(), p_model.normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
  glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eIndex_Vb]);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * p_model.indices.size(), p_model.indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  GLint mat4_pos0 = 3;

  GLint shinyPos = 7;
  GLint materialPos = 8;

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eModel_Vb]);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mat4_pos0 + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(mat4_pos0 + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4),
                          (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * i * 4));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(mat4_pos0 + i, 1);
  }

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eShiny_Vb]);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(shinyPos);
  glVertexAttribPointer(shinyPos, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glVertexAttribDivisor(shinyPos, 1);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eSpecular_Vb]);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(materialPos);
  glVertexAttribPointer(materialPos, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glVertexAttribDivisor(materialPos, 1);
}
```

Called once per frame.

```
    void Mesh::draw(std::vector<Object*> const & p_objects, GLuint p_program)
    {
      std::vector<glm::mat4> models;
      std::vector<glm::float32> shinies;
      std::vector<glm::vec3> specularColors;

      models.reserve(p_objects.size());
      shinies.reserve(p_objects.size());
      specularColors.reserve(p_objects.size());

      for (int index = 0;
      index < p_objects.size();
        index++)
      {
        models.push_back(p_objects[index]->getTransform());
        shinies.push_back(p_objects[index]->getShininess());
        specularColors.push_back(p_objects[index]->getSpecularColor());
      }

      unsigned int bytesOfModels = models.size() * sizeof(models[0]);
      unsigned int bytesOfShinies = shinies.size() * sizeof(shinies[0]);
      unsigned int bytesOfSpecularColors = specularColors.size() * sizeof(specularColors[0]);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eModel_Vb]);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesOfModels, models.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eShiny_Vb]);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesOfShinies, shinies.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, d->vertexArrayBuffers[eSpecular_Vb]);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesOfSpecularColors, specularColors.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    //  glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, d->drawCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, models.size());

    //  glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, d->drawCount, models.size());

      glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES,
                                        d->drawCount,
                                        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                                        0,
                                        p_objects.size(),
                                        0);
    }
```

Called once per frame

```
void GenericRenderer::renderObjects(std::vector<Object*> p_objects)
{
  if (p_objects.empty())
  {
    return;
  }
  m_texture->bind(0);
  m_shader->bind();
  m_shader->updateCamera(m_camera);
  m_shader->updateLightSource(*m_light);
  m_shader->updateObjects(p_objects);
  m_mesh->bind();

  for (size_t index = 0;
  index < p_objects.size();
    index++)
  {
    p_objects[index]->setOrigin(m_camera);
    p_objects[index]->updateTransform();
  }
  m_mesh->draw(p_objects, m_shader->getProgram());

  m_mesh->unbind();
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 camera;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; 
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord; 
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal; 
layout (location = 3) in mat4 model; 
layout (location = 7) in float materialShininess; 
layout (location = 8) in vec3 materialSpecularColor; 

out vec3 fragVert;
out vec2 fragTexCoord;
out vec3 fragNormal;
out mat4 fragModel;
out float fragMaterialShininess;
out vec3 fragMaterialSpecularColor;

void main()
{
  fragModel = model;
  fragTexCoord = texCoord;
  fragNormal = normal;
  fragVert = position;
  fragMaterialShininess = materialShininess;
  fragMaterialSpecularColor = materialSpecularColor;
  gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 150

uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform float exposure;
uniform float lightDistanceModifier;

uniform sampler2D tex;

uniform struct Light {
   vec3 position;
   vec3 intensities; //a.k.a the color of the light
   float attenuation;
   float ambientCoefficient;
} light;

in vec2 fragTexCoord;
in vec3 fragNormal;
in vec3 fragVert;
in mat4 fragModel;
in float fragMaterialShininess;
in vec3 fragMaterialSpecularColor;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    vec3 normal = normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(fragModel))) * fragNormal);
    vec3 surfacePos = vec3(fragModel * vec4(fragVert, 1));
    vec4 surfaceColor = texture(tex, fragTexCoord);
    vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(light.position - surfacePos);
    vec3 surfaceToCamera = normalize(cameraPosition - surfacePos);

    //ambient
    vec3 ambient = light.ambientCoefficient * surfaceColor.rgb * light.intensities;

    //diffuse
    float diffuseCoefficient = max(0.0, dot(normal, surfaceToLight));
    vec3 diffuse = diffuseCoefficient * surfaceColor.rgb * light.intensities;

    //specular
    float specularCoefficient = 0.0;
    if(diffuseCoefficient > 0.0)
        specularCoefficient = pow(max(0.0, dot(surfaceToCamera, reflect(-surfaceToLight, normal))), fragMaterialShininess);
    vec3 specular = specularCoefficient * fragMaterialSpecularColor * light.intensities;

    //attenuation
    float distanceToLight = length(light.position - surfacePos);
    distanceToLight *= lightDistanceModifier;
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (1.0 + light.attenuation * pow(distanceToLight, 2));

    //linear color (color before gamma correction)
    vec3 linearColor = ambient + attenuation*(diffuse + specular);

    //final color (after gamma correction)
    vec3 gamma = vec3(1.0/2.2);

    vec3 mapped = vec3(1.0) - exp(-linearColor * exposure);
    mapped = pow(mapped, vec3(1.0 / gamma));

    finalColor = vec4(mapped, surfaceColor.a);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i replaced the fragment shader to return just white to almost no effect whatsoever.

Comment: I don't understand, people vote to close, delete and downvote questions and answers, without saying why? How am i supposed to format my stuff if nobody tells me why it's considered inappropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL state changes are very expensive. If you are rendering 20000 objects individually per frame then you re most likely CPU bound. Your goal should be to render as many vertices as possible with as few state changes as possible.

If your 20000 objects are all using the same model then your situation is a prime candidate for [instanced rendering](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html). Instanced rendering lets you render the same model thousands of times in one draw call. If you couple this with a separate vertex buffer that contains WVP matrices for each model then you can render each of those model instances at a unique location within the world.

Be warned though, instanced rendering isn't some sort of panacea to all your draw call woes. It has it's own unique overhead with constructing a buffer of MVP matrices on the CPU each frame. If the number of instances you're rendering isn't at least in the hundreds you'll likely see worse performance than your current rendering method.

EDIT: You already using instanced rendering, my apologies.

After reading your code more thoroughly you are likely right in your assumption that you're GPU bound. However, it's not currently clear why you are constructing specular and shininess buffers once per frame when these attributes tend to remain constant for a material.

Comment: I'll update my question, i'm using instanced rendering already. My draw call is a single glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex. Or did I not undestand something?

Comment: I did it party as an exercise, to see if it worked. Also, i'm going to need something like that, as i thought i'd indicate how damaged something is by having a float value that a shader somehow uses to make it look like more damaged. Does it matter if I use multiple buffers and glBufferData or a single buffer and glBufferSubData?

Comment: glBufferSubData should be marginally faster. I was surprised to see the changing specular values as it is an usual approach. You're buffering a lot of extra data per frame, some of which will be for objects that may be completely occluded by others. The usual approach for showing damage on objects is to use decals. Though if you're not using deferred rendering and screen space techniques they can be tricky to implement.

Comment: I'm really a newb with OpenGL, but my idea was this. I'd have 2 textures, one for the "brand new" and one for the "Utterly damaged" state. Then, I'd just meld the textures based on how damaged the thing is. Maybe for some (few) big objects I'd use a different method.

Comment: In that case you still don't need separate specular data for each instance that changes every frame. In your fragment shader have 4 texture samplers (diffuse_regular, diffuse_damaged, specular_regular, specular_damaged). Your specular textures should be RGBA with the shininess stored in the alpha channel. Then all you need is a 'damage factor' per vertex per instance to blend between the two sets of textures which could be something as small as an unsigned short.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In not looking for anything that specific though, but i get the idea. I was thinking that the mat4 was so big already that anything else would not matter. I don't think there is any way to test if an object is occluded by others? Isn't this what the GPU is supposed to worry about?

Comment: If one object is occluded by the other _and_ you have depth testing switched on _and_ the nearer object is drawn before the further then the _fragment_ shader won't be run. There are ways to test for occlusion but with so many objects your best bet is really just to make sure you only send objects to the renderer if they are within the view frustum and also to make your vertex shader as light as possible.